# Linking To Photos ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am simply trying to link a thumbnail photo to the full page view of the photo. I thought I could do something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mazzoart.com/Auctions/Auction/{id}"><img width="70" height="70" src="@Model.ImageURL" title="@Model.Title" /></a>
```

But that doesn't work I get the following error message:

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Auction(Int64)' in 'MyAuctionApp.Controllers.AuctionsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.*

How do I do this?

Thanks, 
CM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the `id` from the `Model` too, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mazzoart.com/Auctions/Auction/@Model.Id">
    <img width="70" height="70" src="@Model.ImageURL" title="@Model.Title" />
</a>
```

In your code, the actual URL that you link to will end with the literal string `"{id}"`.
Such notation is valid in route definitions (it is used to map incoming values to named parameters), but it will very likely never be valid in a View.